# How can I get the badge behind the collapsing menu with bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, typescript, react-redux, bootstrap-4

With migrating from bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4 the items didn't line up anymore. I have search the whole Internet for a solution but I'm out of options now (and patience.. haha)

This is how it looks now:

[image]

I like to have the badge to the right side of the text.

Here is the code:

```
<div className="list-group">
<a href="#Expamle" data-toggle="collapse" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example
        <span className="badge badge-default badge-pill">3</span></a>

<div id="Expamle" className="collapse">
    <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <label className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-1</label>
    </div>
    <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <label className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-2</label>
    </div>
    <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
        <label className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-3</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean "behind"? Do you mean to the right of the text?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/badge/

May something with your custom css, by default it looks to be working normally. I also dont see `badge-default` or `badge-pill` in the new documentation. https://jsfiddle.net/ogatpw55/

Comment: @ZimSystem On the right side, like Example (3)

Comment: @RickSibley That is why I'm frustrated, because I cannot find the issue and everything seems fine. Very little custom css because of a bootstrap-theme, but I will check. Could it also have something to do with that this code is wrapped by a <fieldset></fieldset> ?

Comment: The code you've post doesn't repro the issue. Can you clean it up so that it does?

Comment: I dont think it is the `fieldset`. I dropped it in a test environment wrapped by fieldset and it did not change. Is the code you are working on live? If so post the link so I can inspect the page. Note: I found the class `badge-pill` but still dont see `badge-default` is this a custom style?

Comment: It was custom by a bootstrap-theme. Left the flex-column out and it worked like expected. Thank you for all the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="#Expamle" data-toggle="collapse" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">
  Example 
  <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
</a>


<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#Expamle" data-toggle="collapse" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example
        <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span></a>

  <div id="Expamle" class="collapse">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <label class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <label class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <label class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I assume you have set a fixed width on `list-group-item`. Therefore, its content wraps because its `display` is `block`.

```css
.list-group-item {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}
```

---

Bootstrap does not have `badge-default` class. It has only the following the classes.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="badge badge-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="badge badge-secondary">Secondary</span>
<span class="badge badge-success">Success</span>
<span class="badge badge-danger">Danger</span>
<span class="badge badge-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="badge badge-info">Info</span>
<span class="badge badge-light">Light</span>
<span class="badge badge-dark">Dark</span>
```

---

It is useless to use `flex-column` because the display of `list-group-item` is `block`, not `flex`. `flex-column` works only on `flex` elements.

Comment: The list-group-item was set to flex, but removing the flex-column did the trick. Thank you for explaining and I will change the badge-default as well!

Comment: @MariaT You are welcome. But you do not need to set it to flex.

Comment: This was set by default in the bootstrap-theme, but I disabled it. Not always easy working with a theme :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

heres the code for it:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#Expamle" data-toggle="collapse" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example
        <span class="badge">5</span></a>
    
    <div id="Expamle" class="collapse">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <label class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <label class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <label class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column">Example list-item-3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqbe1kwk/